Setting up bottom nav view with navController causes view model cleared when back pressed
My current version of navigation is:
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.8.0")
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.8.0")

Inside a fragment I have a FragmentContainerView and BottomNavigationView. I set them up using navController like so:
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

   val navView: BottomNavigationView = binding.bottomNav
   val navHostFragment = (childFragmentManager.findFragmentById(
        R.id.navHostFragment
   ) as NavHostFragment)
   navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
}

Whenever I navigate through tabs (e.g. home -> profile -> home) the ProfileViewModel is saved (meaning its onCleared is not called). But if I press back button when profile tab is selected, the ProfileViewModel's onCleared is being called.
I even tried to add OnBackPressedCallback to override any back press but its handleOnBackPressed is not being called:
requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(viewLifecycleOwner, onBackPressedCallback)

How can I make the navController to stop clearing the view model when back button is pressed?

EDIT: I did not read your question carefully enough.
You are experiencing the effects of the new "multiple back stack" support in the navigation library.
https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/backstack/multi-back-stacks
When you press the Home tab from the Profile screen, you are actually switching back stacks under the hood.  Because Profile screen is still in the back stack for the Profile tab, it's view model store is still active and the view model is not cleared.
When you press Back from the Profile screen, you are popping the back stack.  This destroys the fragment, which clears its view model store, along with the view model.
This behavior is all by design.
I am currently in the process of integrating Navigation component into my app, and let me say: you are not the only one struggling to get "expected" behavior out of their app.
You can try turning off back stack save state and see if the behavior works better for your case:
https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/ui/NavigationUI#setupWithNavController(com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationBarView,androidx.navigation.NavController,kotlin.Boolean)

Refer to https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel/viewmodel-apis
Having the ViewModel cleared is generally a good thing; usually you want to make sure the ViewModel is not displaying stale data in the UI.
But if you really really want that ViewModel to retain data while you navigate around, a simple way is to scope the ViewModel to the Activity:
val viewModel: SharedViewModel by activityViewModels()

Both the Fragment and Activity have ViewModel stores, by using the Activity's you can keep the ViewModel from clearing while you navigate to a different fragment.

Thanks for the response. But this won't work if i inject view model into compose inside the fragment.

My problem is view model stays alive when user navigates through bottom navigation view's tabs; and it gets killed if the user presses the back button to go to the first tab.

See my updated answer.

Tnx for the update. I will try the solution you proposed, hoping this changes the behavior. Another question popped in my mind: Would the problem still exist if I change the whole XML navigation to Compose navigation?

I honestly don't know.  I'm struggling just to make it work with views.  But I think understanding how those multiple back stacks work is the key to your problem.

Tnx for your help a lot. I know we both didn't found the solution yet, but it gave me a lot of insights; so thank you.
